# Wrong amount of free disk space seen after using Gparted

Tags: disk-usage, gparted

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 in a VM. I have recently resized the hard drive of this VM doubling its size with Gparted. However, when I run `df -h`, Ubuntu still sees the old hard drive space, while Gparted sees the new one.

How can I force a refresh of this so that the OS can see the correct amount of space available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command that resized the filesystem was `sudo lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/sda<number>`. Have a look at [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138090/cant-resize-a-partition-using-resize2fs) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

One way this can happen is if the partition is grown, but the underlying file system has not also been grown.  The ability to detect this situation was added to GParted 0.13.0.  The problem can be fixed by selecting the partition and choosing "Partition --> Check".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this did not work. Ubuntu still sees the old hard drive size.