# Can't resize a partition using resize2fs

Tags: filesystems, virtual-machine, vmware, resize2fs

I recently resized the hard drive of a VM from 150 GB to 500 GB in VMWare ESXi. After doing this, I used Gparted to effectively resize the partition of this image. Now all I have to do is to resize the file system, since it still shows the old value (as you can see from the output of `df -h`):

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/owncloud--vg-root  157G   37G  112G  25% /
udev                           488M  4.0K  488M   1% /dev
tmpfs                          100M  240K  100M   1% /run
none                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                           497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                      236M   32M  192M  14% /boot
```

However, running `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/owncloud--vg-root` returns this:

```
resize2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
The filesystem is already 41608192 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Since Gparted says that my partition is `/dev/sda5`, I also tried running `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda5`, but in this case I got this:

```
resize2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda5
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Finally, this is the output of `pvs`:

```
PV         VG          Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/sda5  owncloud-vg lvm2 a-   499.76g 340.04g
```

`fdisk -l /dev/sda` shows the correct amount of space.

How can I resize the partition so that I can finally make the OS see 500 GB of hard drive?

Comment: `pvs` should show where your vg is located. Where is that?

Comment: @Nils added to the question :)

Comment: Joel gave the right answer. Your question contains now the complete picture of your - quite common - problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you only changed the partition size, you're not ready to resize the logical volume yet. Once the partition is the new size, you need to do a `pvresize` on the PV so the volume group sees the new space. After that you can use `lvextend` to expand the logical volume into the volume group's new space. You can pass `-r` to the `lvextend` command so that it automatically kicks off the `resize2fs` for you.

Personally, I would have just made a new partition and used `vgextend` on it since I've had mixed results with `pvresize`.

Comment: I have run `pvresize` followed by `lvextend -r -L 500G /dev/sda2`, and this is what I get: `Path required for Logical Volume "sda2"
  Please provide a volume group name
  Run 'lvextend --help' for more information.`

Comment: Once you do the `pvresize` you're done dealing with regular partitions. You need to specify the path of the logical volume which in this case is `/dev/mapper/owncloud--vg-root` Personally I'd run `lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/owncloud--vg-root`

Comment: After you run the `pvresize` command, you can verify the space is in the volume group by running the `vgs` command.

Comment: Also, you didn't mention it in your question but does `fdisk -l /dev/sda` show the correct hard drive size? If not you may have to reboot or rescan the SCSI bus.

Comment: That worked, thanks! For some reason it did not autocomplete `/dev/mapper/owncloud--vg-root` and so I kept trying `/sda5` XD

Answer (score 88):

Thanks a lot for @Bratchley answer and the comments. It helped me :)

My environment: Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox 6.1

My case: I created 10GB fixed VDI disk and increased to 30GB dynamic using VirtualBox GUI. But still the increased space is not available to filesystem. Then came across @Bratchley answer.

Steps I ran:

1. Run below command to get PV *(Physical Volume)* name *(Ex: `/dev/sda1`)*

```
sudo pvs
```

2. Resize the PV *(Ex: `sudo pvresize /dev/sda1`)*

```
sudo pvresize <PV name from above step>
```

3. Run below command to get root logical volume name *(Filesystem value of `/` row; ex: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`)*

```
df -h
```

4. Expand logical volume *(ex : `sudo lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`)*:

```
sudo lvextend -r -l +100%FREE <root logical volume name from above step>
```

Comment: Best answer of all!

Comment: Step 3: what does this mean? I have no idea what I'm looking for or how to get that information.

Comment: Run `df -h` command, and look for the Filesystem value of `/` mount path. _(it will be something like `/dev/xxxxx`)_

Comment: Note: Doesn't work with gfs2 filesystem.

Comment: after the last step, it fails with: `inodes (7690084352) must be less than 4294967295`

Comment: how can I install `pvs`?

Comment: @alper, I already have that installed by default. But you may check this for more detailed help: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/pvs-command-not-found/

Comment: I am only joining this stack exchange to upvote you! solved, thanks

Comment: Ahh, that is very kind of you. Again, major credits to @Bratchley answer. I just improvised a little and made it easy to follow steps.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful!

Comment: Thanks a lot - I had to search quite a while to find this easy and working answer!

Answer (score 2):

`sudo btrfs filesystem resize max /` should be able to resize the partition.

Extended virtual disk size up to 100GB but command `df -h` said old spase size after resizing with `fdisk`.

`btrfs` simply resolves the resize2fs: Device or resource busy issue.

Comment: That assumes that the file system is Btrfs, not Ext4 (which is apparently what the OP was using).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, I have checked /etc/fstab and than I realized that I have renamed the VG and this did not change everywhere that rename,  I was able to solve this by renaming back my VG!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must extend your drive size to get all the free space. Then resize your drive to use all the space.

1. Extend drive space

   `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/owncloud--vg-root`
2. Resize drive size

   `resize2fs /dev/mapper/owncloud--vg-root`