# cannot resize disk on aws instance

Tags: aws, resize2fs, volume

I tried following the instructions in:
[Can't resize a partition using resize2fs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138090/cant-resize-a-partition-using-resize2fs)

But nothing seemed to work.

The output of `lsblk` is:

```
[AWS root@archive ~]$ lsblk
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda                          202:0    0   300G  0 disk
├─xvda1                       202:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
├─xvda2                       202:2    0  29.5G  0 part
│ ├─vg_archive-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0 147.6G  0 lvm  /
│ └─vg_archive-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0     2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
├─xvda3                       202:3    0    10G  0 part
│ └─vg_archive-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0 147.6G  0 lvm  /
└─xvda4                       202:4    0   110G  0 part
  └─vg_archive-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0 147.6G  0 lvm  /
```

You can see that 300Gb is available, but I've been unable to extend the root volume from 150Gb.
Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Update: thought I'd add the linux distro, it's old which might be part of the problem...

`Linux version 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b10.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Aug 28 17:19:38 UTC 2013`

As requested in the comments, this is the output from the suggested commands from the link above:

```
[AWS root@archive ~]$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/xvda2 vg_archive lvm2 a--   29.51g    0
  /dev/xvda3 vg_archive lvm2 a--    9.99g    0
  /dev/xvda4 vg_archive lvm2 a--  110.00g    0
[AWS root@archive ~]$ sudo pvresize /dev/xvda2
  Physical volume "/dev/xvda2" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
[AWS root@archive ~]$ sudo pvresize /dev/xvda3
  Physical volume "/dev/xvda3" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
[AWS root@archive ~]$ sudo pvresize /dev/xvda4
  Physical volume "/dev/xvda4" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
[AWS root@archive ~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_archive-lv_root
                      146G  131G  8.0G  95% /
tmpfs                 938M     0  938M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            485M   80M  380M  18% /boot
[AWS root@archive ~]$ sudo lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg_archive-lv_root
  Extending logical volume lv_root to 147.56 GiB
  Logical volume lv_root successfully resized
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 38682624 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

[AWS root@archive ~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_archive-lv_root
                      146G  131G  8.0G  95% /
tmpfs                 938M     0  938M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            485M   80M  380M  18% /boot
```

Update: it would appear the fs type is ext4 from the below output

```
[AWS root@archive ~]$ df -Th
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_archive-lv_root
              ext4    146G  131G  8.0G  95% /
tmpfs        tmpfs    938M     0  938M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1    ext4    485M   80M  380M  18% /boot
```

Update: output of `cfdisk /dev/xvda` as requested:

```
                                                         cfdisk (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)

                                                             Disk Drive: /dev/xvda
                                                      Size: 322122547200 bytes, 322.1 GB
                                             Heads: 255   Sectors per Track: 63   Cylinders: 39162

       Name                 Flags                Part Type         FS Type                       [Label]                   Size (MB)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                   Unusable                                                     1.05          *
       xvda1                Boot                  Primary          Linux ext3                                                 524.29          *
       xvda2                                      Primary          Linux LVM                                                31686.92          *
       xvda3                                      Primary          Linux LVM                                                10731.94          *
       xvda4                                      Primary          Linux LVM                                               118115.03
                                                                   Unusable                                                161063.34          *
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. The question you linked contains several answers; please edit your question to state _which_ steps you followed, and what kind of error messages (if any) you encountered.

Comment: XFS, the default FS for Centos, requires you use `xfs_growfs` instead of `resize2fs`. Could you check if your FS is XFS, and if it is try the steps in [this other QA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362910/trying-to-resize2fs-eb-volume-fails)

Comment: looks like it's ext4 judging by the output of `df -Th`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully resized the disk by doing the following:

After increasing the size of the image in AWS console from 150Gb to 300Gb, I executed the following commands:

```
[AWS root@archive ~]$ pvresize /dev/xvda4
  Physical volume "/dev/xvda4" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
```

REBOOT

```
[AWS root@archive ~]$ growpart /dev/xvda 4
CHANGED: partition=4 start=83875365 old: size=230693400 end=314568765 new: size=545262165,end=629137530
[AWS root@archive ~]$ pvresize /dev/xvda4
  Physical volume "/dev/xvda4" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
[AWS root@archive ~]$ lvextend /dev/vg_archive/lv_root -l+100%FREE
  New size (37776 extents) matches existing size (37776 extents)
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
[AWS root@archive ~]$ resize2fs /dev/vg_archive/lv_root
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 38682624 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

REBOOT again as it wasn't working

```
[AWS root@archive ~]$ lvextend /dev/vg_archive/lv_root -l+100%FREE
  New size (37776 extents) matches existing size (37776 extents)
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
[AWS root@archive ~]$ resize2fs /dev/vg_archive/lv_root
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 38682624 blocks long.  Nothing to do!

[AWS root@archive ~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_archive-lv_root
                      146G  131G  8.0G  95% /
tmpfs                 938M     0  938M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            485M   80M  380M  18% /boot
[AWS root@archive ~]$ pvresize /dev/xvda4
  Physical volume "/dev/xvda4" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized
[AWS root@archive ~]$ lvextend /dev/vg_archive/lv_root -l+100%FREE
  Extending logical volume lv_root to 297.56 GiB
  Logical volume lv_root successfully resized
[AWS root@archive ~]$ resize2fs /dev/vg_archive/lv_root
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem at /dev/vg_archive/lv_root is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old desc_blocks = 10, new_desc_blocks = 19
Performing an on-line resize of /dev/vg_archive/lv_root to 78004224 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/vg_archive/lv_root is now 78004224 blocks long.

[AWS root@archive ~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_archive-lv_root
                      293G  131G  149G  47% /
tmpfs                 938M     0  938M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1            485M   80M  380M  18% /boot
```

So I'm not entirely sure what command required a reboot, but I had to reboot in order for the resize to succeed.

I hope this helps someone else

Comment: looking at the sequence of commands, looks likely that I needed to reboot between `pvresize` and `lvextend` + `resize2fs`