# Expand logical volume - Ubuntu on Proxmox

Tags: ubuntu, proxmox

After expanding the size of the disk on my Proxmox hypervisor from 8GB to 18GB I am trying to see this new space on my Ubuntu 20.04 VM:
[image]

These are the commands I'd run on the VM

```bsh
# Physical volume is called /dev/sda3
sudo pvs

# resize the Physical Volume (PV)
sudo pvresize /dev/sda3

# root logical volume is
df -h

# expand the logical volume
sudo lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

# resize my number 3 partition (this gave me 17GB on sda3)
sudo growpart /dev/sda 3
```

[image]

I can see it on the sda3 partition!

[image]

Want to see the 18GB on `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/583544 - am following these instructions

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Grow the filesystem too

Comment: I think the order of the commands was wrong. It should be growpart -> pvresize -> lvextend.

Comment: Thanks both - have added an answer below.

Answer (score 12):

https://packetpushers.net/ubuntu-extend-your-default-lvm-space/ was the article which helped me the most.

In summary

```bsh
# allocate more space on hypervisor

# make the partition see the space (dev/sda3, Resize, Write, quit)
sudo cfdisk

# extend the physical volume from the partition
sudo pvresize /dev/sda3

# extend LV to use up all space from VG
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

# resize file system
sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

# check can see the space on filesystem
df -h
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to increase volume size.

- Increase/resize disc from GUI console
- Identify Linux partition:

  ```shell
  sudo fdisk -l
  ```
- Extend physical drive partition

  ```shell
  growpart /dev/sda 3
  ```
- Instruct LVM that disk size has changed

  ```shell
  sudo pvresize /dev/sda3
  ```
- Find Entry with starting LV

  ```shell
  lvdisplay
  ```
- Resize LV

  ```shell
  sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  ```